# How to set a class on angular accordion header when pane is open?

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Angular UI Bootstrap accordion component, [from here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
                <div accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
                    <div accordion-group heading="Static Header, initially expanded" is-open="true">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia aspernatur consequuntur sed pariatur laborum officiis asperiores repellat velit, omnis. Voluptate, illum animi? Veniam odit nemo repudiandae id blanditiis similique ullam consequuntur harum aut possimus deserunt sit odio sapiente, dolorum dolor!
                    </div>
                    <div accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
                        {{group.content}}
                    </div>
                    <div accordion-group heading="Dynamic Body Content">
                        <p>The body of the accordion group grows to fit the contents</p>
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
                            <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="oneAtATime"> <label class="checkbox">Open only one at a time</label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The controller is very basic, [and is here if interested](http://cl.ly/code/1g2e0T381k1d/accordion.js).

What I am trying to do is display a disclosure triangle next to the accordion headers, and have them switch to show that the pane is open.

[image]

I have done all the necessary LESS/CSS to display a unicode character using the pseudoclass "before".  I have one class for closed and one for open.

The thing I can't figure out is how to *easily* detect that a particular header has an open pane.  The class is toggled on the *content*, not the headers. I'm trying to do it with a class instead of a simple toggle so it will also work if the pane is **defaulted** to opened.

Thoughts?

Comment: Doesn't the accordion already has native support for this? This page: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ has an example accordion with an arrow. Look for "I can have markup, too!"

Comment: they have it at the end of the line, as a glyph icon.  I need it to the left.  the issue here i think is that they don't easily expose the html template.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of playing (since AngularJS is new to me), here's a working example:

First, you have chevrons in glyphicons but not the ones from your picture, although we can easily create them in css:

```
.caret-right {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
right: 0px;
border-top: 5px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
border-left: 5px solid #595959;
top:3px;
content: "";
}

.caret-down {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
right: 0px;
border-left: 5px solid transparent;
border-right: 5px solid transparent;
border-top: 5px solid #595959;
top:5px;
content: "";
}
```

Your accordion has to be in the format:

```
<accordion-group is-open="status.isFirstOpen">
  <accordion-heading>
     <i class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'caret-down': status.isFirstOpen, 'caret-right': !status.isFirstOpen}"></i> 
     Static Header, initially expanded
  </accordion-heading>This content is straight in the template.
</accordion-group>
```

The `is-open="status.isFirstOpen"` indicates that this accordion element should be open by default.

`ng-class="{'caret-down': status.isFirstOpen, 'caret-right': !status.isFirstOpen}` says that if it is open (*status.isFirstOpen*), apply the `caret-down` css class and if it is not open, apply the `caret-right` css class.

The `status.isFirstOpen` is for the initial toggle, for the rest you can use `status.open`.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/FAFfxxvbU5iCw5bkjIJ0?p=preview)**